# How can I create a symbolic link that depends on other files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, symlink

I know my topic is a little confusing, but here is what I want to do.

I have a file which I would like to create a link to in my home directory `~/bin`, but when I execute the file that is symbolically linked, the file requires another file in its directory. Therefore, it fails to run because it cannot find the other file. What can I do?

Comment: Add a link to the other file, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have two simple solutions.

1. edit the shell script to point to the absolute path of the file, not just the the basename.

   `./path/to/file.sh`
      VS
      `file.sh`

   so something like this should do what your after. `sed -i 's|file.sh|./path/to/file.sh|g' ~/bin/script.sh` it searches your symlinked file, script.sh in this case, and replaces the call to file.sh to ./path/to/file.sh. note you often see `sed` use /'s. but it can use just about anything as a delimiter, if you wish to use /'s here you will need to escape them. /. you may want to consider escaping the . (period) as well, but in this case its not necessary. If you are new to `sed` realize that the `-i` flag means it will edit the file in place. Lastly, realize its a simple search and replace operation and you may chose to do it by hand.
2. The second way is to create a `ln -s` to the file as you did with the other file so there exists a symbolic link between both files.

   `ln -s /far/off/script.sh ~/bin/script.sh`

   and

   `ln -s /far/off/file.sh ~/bin/file.sh`

[more on symlinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems)

Comment: Numero UNO FTW!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather create a script file in ~/bin/` that calls your executable from the appropriate directory.

Here is an example using /sbin/ifconfig:

```
$ cat > ~/bin/file
#!/bin/bash

file=/sbin/ifconfig
cd `dirname $file`
`basename $file` 
(ctr+d)
$ chmod +x ~/bin/file
$ file
```

Here you should see the output of `ifconfig` but the point is: its get executed from the `/sbin` directory. So if ifconfig had dependencies it would work properly. Just replace `/sbin/ifconfig` with your absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can modify your script as

```
pushd ~/bin

##### your script here

popd
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `readlink` and `dirname` will get the actual directory of the script:

```
my_dir=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")
source "$my_dir/other_file"
```